# how do i use jquery to add path on my img src?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a thumbnail img rescaled to 250px x 250px, when i clicked on it, it will pop out another div showing the same img at 750px x 750px. I just target to the same src as my thumbnail img to show on full screen since it is actually a very big image, like so.

HTML

```
<div class="img_thumb_holder float-l"><img class="img_thumb" src="images/andrew.jpg"></div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $(".img_thumb_holder").on('click', function() {
    var img = $(this).children(".img_thumb").attr("src"); //store the src path into img
    $(".full_image_pic").attr("src", img); // display on my 750px by 750px div
});
```

What i want to do now is that i show a cropped thumbnail image, on click my full image div will display the full image instead of scaling this time. I assume i will have 2 images to do it, so basically i crop it to 250px by 250px for the thumbnail img, and another image is a full image

assuming my thumbnail path is: images/andrew.jpg - 250px by 250px
my full image path is: images/andrew1.jpg - 750px by 750px

how do i add the extra letter/number "1" to

```
var img = $(this).children(".img_thumb").attr("src"); // currently images/andrew.jpg, i want to make it store as andrew1.jpg
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var img = $(this).children(".img_thumb").attr("src");
var newImg=img.split(".");
img=newImg[0]+"1."+newImg[1];
```

Comment: close enough, it became andrew1jpg , lack of a . inbetween to make it andrew1.jpg, can i know the logic as well for the splitting?

Comment: well between mages/andrew.jpg and images/andrew1.jpg there is difference is 1 which is before .jpg . if you wanna add 1 before .jpg you have split it by something then add 1 and re merge it.here i split by "." which is unique and it will make my work done.

Comment: working now, i assume var newImg=img.split("."); find the . in the andrew.jpg, and split andrew into [0] and jpg into [1], so u added a "1." and add back [1] which is jpg in it. Am i correct?

Comment: can u also teach me how i can retrieve the height and width of the img variable now that i got img = images/andrew1.jpg, i tried alert(img.width) but it says undefined.

Comment: try $(this).children(".img_thumb").width(); $(this).children(".img_thumb").height();